# How to find out if for loop iteration is the last one

Tags: java

I have following loop

```
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) { }
```

how do i find out if current iteration is the last iteration in java. thanks. Value I am getting dynamically.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes and closing votes. This is a very legitimate question.

Comment: Yes it is legitim! When i learned programming I often thought if whether using len or len-1.

Comment: sorry all, I had a confusion regarding this thing.

Comment: @user30080 - no apology required - the question as others have noted may be simple to some but welcome on SO and in our community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per your question if your comparison value is dynamic

```
int myval = 1000;

    for(int i=0;i<myval;i++) { 

        if(i == myval -1){
            // last work
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check that `i` equals `999`, unless of course it is additionally modified inside the loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
    if (i == 999) {
        // Last iteration
    }
    ... // More code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just check your run-variable. `if(i == 999)`...

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested, you can see `if(i==999)`. This will work most of the times, but not always.

If you modify `i` inside the loop, you may find yourself in iteration 999 several times, or never.

Also, if you use `break` or `return` inside the loop, you won't get to the 999th iteration.

Answer (score 0):

in practise this looks a bit different then the other answers showed:

```
int len = 1000;
for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
  if (i == len-1) {
      // action for last iteration
  }
}
```